# Can I stream music/video from Internet or NAS to PS3

Tags: internet, nas, streaming, ps3, mybook

I have a Western Digital MyBook World NAS drive, and I am thinking about getting a PS3, so that I only need one unit to play games, blu-ray, and streaming media.

**Questions:**

1. Can I stream media from my NAS to PS3
2. If I can stream from NAS to PS3, are there any format limitations? (i.e. MKV)
3. Does PS3 support streaming services like BBC iPlayer etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) support is what you need between these systems. It is a standard for streaming media.

You will need to verify your MyBook NAS has DLNA / UPnP Support in the firmware you have installed on it or upgrade to firmware that has DLNA support. The WD website listed support for DLNA.

Your Playstation3 will likewise need DLNA support as well. I don't have a PS3 but believe it has support as well.